# How to simplify assigning the same converter to multiple bindings (windows store app)?

Tags: binding, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue3, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

The "Converter" Property is on Binding, not on TextBlock, so I can't use a style on TextBlock.

Each binding is different, so I can't create a single Binding resource.

So, how to avoid setting the same converter 3 times?

EDIT: I'll try to explain a bit more. What I'm looking for is a way to give the binding object a default converter, so that I don't have to set the same converter over and over again when I create many bindings with the same converter.

So if I can write sth like:

```
<Grid DefaultBindingConverter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}">
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue1}"/>
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue2}"/>
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsTrue3}"/>
    ...
```

Clearly this is not correct, just to illustrate my idea.

Hope this time I explained it clear enough.

Comment: Hard to understand your question. 
You can use a style in TextBlock. 
And, I hardly understand what 'single binding resource' stands for.

Comment: if you create a style on TextBlock, you can't set the Converter property because it's a property of Binding class. You also can't set the Visibility because each Binding has a different path.

Comment: "single Binding resource" just means creating a Binding object as a static resource, but because the binding path are different, I have to create 3 binding objects instead of a "single" one, which defeats the purpose of creating a reusable resource

Answer (score 0):

Let's touch about two issues in your question.

**1. Single Resource**

It seems that you are misunderstood about the `StaticResource` definition in Converter.
The `BooleanToVisibility` that you've coded, for example, is worked not three-times-copied object. It only declared once and used three times.

Let's take another example, if you code as below

```
int i;
i=1;
i=2;
i=3;
```

You declared `i` once, and used it three times. Likewise, `StaticResource` that you used are works as similar. You may declare `x:Key="BooleanToVisibility"` in `<UserControl.Resources>` or `<Application.Resources>` tag, that's it.

**2. Style usage**

If you want to set Style in TextBlock, you may use below approach.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Number1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>
            <!-- Define your Styles here -->                
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
<TextBlock>
```

As you can see above, You can expand `Style` XAML attribute into inner tag.

**==EDIT==**

I now understand your intention. You probably want to apply Converter in a hierarchical inheritance manner like a DataContext works.

Sadly, as far as I know, that is NOT possible under XAML. Because each Binding is just a property so that it has to be applied one-by-one.

Possible workaround is to use code-behind to enumerate elements and apply them.

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    var textbox = (TextBox)this.FindName("TextBox" + i);
    var binding = new Binding("IsTrue" + i);
    binding.Converter = new YourDefaultConverter();
    textbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

hope this helps to reduce your chores.

Comment: You didn't read my question nor my comment carefully, I am talking about the single Binding object as a resource, not the converter resource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but using MVVM, I'm also trying to avoid any code-behind. So I think I'll just live with that, and hope the XAML team come up with better syntax in the future

Comment: @NanLi // Yes, I strictly made my app in MVVM approach for a while, but recent days with win-rt, code-behind works are increased.